# Minimal polynomial of a complex number $z$ that is also an algebraic integer does not have $z$ as a repeated root

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ be an algebraic integer, and let $P\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $(X-z)^2 \nmid P(X)$.

**My attempt:**
My first idea was to prove that $P'(z)\neq0$ because $z$ would be a root of the derivative of $P$ if and only if it would be a repeated root, but I don't know anything about the structure of $P'$ so I this was the end for this idea.
On an intuitive level I understand why this statement should be true because minimal polynomial basically means "what other factors are we forced to add to $(X-z)$ to make it an integer polynomial", and it seems logical that it makes no sense to add the same factor again. However, I am unable to formalize this idea.

Comment: The minimal polynomial is monic and has degree at least $1$, so you certainly know *something* about the structure of $P'$...

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the degree of $P$ compared to other polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ which might have $z$ as a root?

Comment: Thank you all! I got it. I can consider $D$ to be the greatest common divisor of $P$ and $P'$, and both of these polynomials have integer coefficients so $D$ is from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as well, but $(X-z)$ divides both $P$ and $P'$ so it divides $D$, which means that $D$ has nonzero degree, but it divides a irreducible polynomial of degree $deg(P)$ so $D=P$ which implies that $P$ divides $P'$ which is obviously false since $deg(P')=deg(P)-1$. I appreciate the hints, and I am grateful that you didn't give me the full solution because it felt better to find it myself.

Comment: Let $n=\deg(f)>1$. Then $xf'-(n-1)f$ is another minimal polynomial so $xf'-(n-1)f=f$ by uniqueness of $f$. The solution is $f=x^n$ , reducible. Contradiction.